# Question on pulling limit operator inside expression

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity, proof-explanation

> Let's consider:
> $
> f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ where $f,g\in\mathcal{C^1}$ and $f'(x)$ denotes the first derivative. We further assume that
> $$
> \lim\limits_{x\to a}\left(\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-g(a)\right)=0.
> $$
> I am wondering if this allows us to say that $f'(a)=g(a)$?

---

If I have understood the workings of continuity and limit operator correctly I would say that this conclusion is **false**.

The reason is that we don't know if the function $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with
$$
h(x)=\left(\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-g(a)\right),
$$
is continuous. If it *were* continuous then we could pull the limit operator inside (in this case we omit the parentheses) and conclude:
$$
0=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\left(\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-g(a)\right)=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(a)=f'(a)-g(a)\\
\implies f'(a)=g(a)
$$

---

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You are only using the fact that *subtraction* is continuous (in order to pull the limit inside of subtraction). Which it definitely is.

Comment: @StinkingBishop, I don't understand your comment. What do you mean by saying that I use  that substraction is continuous? When I pull the limit inside I have assumed $h$ to be continuous. In particular this would require the quotient $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ to be continuous.

Comment: You did not pull the limit inside of $h$, as this would mean this: $\frac{f(\lim_{x\to a}x)-f(a)}{(\lim_{x\to a}x)-a}-g(a)$. You have just pulled the limit inside the "minus" sign: $\lim_{x\to a}(A(x)-B(x))=\lim_{x\to a}A(x)-\lim_{x\to a}B(x)$. Which is always allowed.

Comment: @StinkingBishop substraction is only continuous if $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are continuous. In my case, where $A(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$, the function $A(x)$ is not defined at $x=a$, so we can't say that $A(x)$ is continuous. First we have to set $A(a)$ a value so that it becomes continuous. I think it is obvious which value to assign $A(a)$. After that we can pull the lilmit inside.